# How to float divs without using tables

Tags: css

Hi how do i have divs layout like this using CSS float and other methods. i am trying to avoid using tables and learn how to float divs properly.
[image: This layout]
Thanks

Comment: post your html and css. Also a fiddle.

Comment: I would suggest looking for a tutorial instead of using SO for this if you don't have any code yet. This is a good start http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 2):

first id use a main div with display:block;
then inside that main div for your example create 4 sub divs with display:inline-block;

Comment: Thanks thats what i was looking for, as every time i try to float these divs it gets push down instead of aligning to the left or right. Having those display: block and inline it takes away the those automatically created space

Comment: im relieved that i could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at solutions like [Singularity](http://singularity.gs) or [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net). Both capable grid frameworks giving you a helping hand accomplishing exactly what you intend to do and keep the necessity of math out of your head. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sigh those were a lot of boxes ;D. I couldn't exactly see the dimensions of each box but I did my best to replicate what you showed (no absolute or relative positioning used!).

Here's the jsFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8nGLY/)  ***The formatting is odd, jsFiddle's tidyUp is not working for me***

Here's the codepen: [link](http://codepen.io/nickgofly/pen/tCGLu)   ***Use this one instead***

The trick is to use float: left when you want things to stack horizontally. When you want them to stack vertically, just wrap those elements in a container and make sure each has display: block. You use these two things to accomplish this sort of thing.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left0">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="left1"></div>
    <div id="left2"></div>
    <div id="row1">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2"></div>
    <div id="row3">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{ /*includes the border in height&width*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div{ /*gives us some general spacing*/
    margin: 5px;
    background: lightblue;
}

#container{
    width: 1200px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: lightgray;
}
/*gives a float-left property to first-level children*/
#container > div{
  float: left;
}

#container > div > div{
  border: 1px solid red;
}


#left0{
  width: 50px;
}

#left0 > div{ /*styles for little boxes*/
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#left1{
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
}

#left2{
  width: 150px;
  height: 230px;
}

#row1{
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
}

#row1 div:nth-child(1){
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  height: 40px;
}

#row1 div:nth-child(2){
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  height: 40px;
}

#row2{
  width: 600px;
  height: 70px;
}

#row3{
  width: 600px;
  height:90px;
}

#row3 div:nth-child(1){
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

#row3 div:nth-child(2){
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
}
```

I'll comment explaining some of the css3 selectors I used in case you're not familiar with them.

Comment: :nth-child(n)   This selector chooses the 'n'th child from the div. For example, #first div:nth-child(1) will select the first child of the #first element.  the '>' selector just means direct child. For example, #first > div will select all the divs that are the direct children of the #first element. I used these selectors to not use too many ids and classes.